# gunicorn Serve Error(500) in django 3.2 app on localhost

Tags: django, gunicorn, wsgi, django-3.2

I'm trying to serve my Django 3.2 application using `gunicorn` on my localhost. First time, it ran correctly. Later, I changed DEBUG parameter to False in `settings.py` and I run it again. This time it gives me a server error. In terminal there is no error. See the pictures below. Why is this happening ? How to fix this ?

Error Page
[image]

settings.py

[image]

terminal

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to use it in your localhost you need to change the `DEBUG = True` instead of `DEBUG = False` and It will work smoothly